# Updating null and related values inside Cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

#### Before Script Runs

```
Seller_No   |Product_No|Product_Status |
99999       |100000    |Availalble     |
88888       |100000    |Null           |
```

---

#### Expected Results

```
Seller_No   |Product_No|Product_Status |
99999       |100000    |Removal        |
88888       |100000    |Available      |
```

---

I have the following script. I am required to use the cursor. This will always be a small batch so no worries on overhead for the system.

The scenario is that we changed to a new seller. I want to mark the new seller as 'available' while changing the old seller to 'removal'.

The following is the script so far. I've been using the null value for searching the correct rows. However, I have to somehow find the old make it null before making the new item 'available'. Is it possible to do all this inside the cursor?

```
    USE [OutletRetail]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [Outlet].[sp_UpdateProductStatus]    Script Date: 01/16/2014 19:58:47 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
    GO

    --Updates Product status codes to Available if NULL
    ALTER   PROCEDURE [Outlet].[sp_UpdateProductStatus]
    AS

    DECLARE @strProductNo varchar(20)
    DECLARE @strSellerNo1 varchar(10)
    DECLARE @strSellerNo2 varchar(10)


    DECLARE UpdateProductCursor CURSOR FOR

        SELECT Product_No, Seller_No
        FROM Outlet.tblProductMaster
        WHERE Product_Status IS NULL

    OPEN UpdateProductCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM UpdateProductCursor INTO @strProduct_No, @strSellerNo1

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

    BEGIN

        SET @strSellerNo2 = NULL

        SELECT  @strSellerNo2 = Seller_No
        FROM    Outlet.tblProductMaster
        WHERE   Product_No = @strProductNo
            AND Seller_No &lt;&gt; @strSellerNo1
            AND Product_Status = 'Available'


    IF (@strSellerNo2 IS NULL)
    BEGIN
            UPDATE Outlet.tblProductMaster
            SET Product_Status = 'Available'
            WHERE Product_No = @strProductNo
                AND Seller_No = @strSellerNo1
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

After you find `@strSellerNo2` you can update the old seller_No (99999) to have  `Product_Status  = null`

```
 ........



     SET @strSellerNo2 = NULL

    SELECT  @strSellerNo2 = Seller_No
    FROM    Outlet.tblProductMaster
    WHERE   Product_No = @strProductNo
        AND Seller_No &lt;&gt; @strSellerNo1
        AND Product_Status = 'Available'

  IF(@strSellerNo2 is not null)
  BEGIN
      update Outlet.tblProductMaster
      set Product_Status  = null
      where Seller_No    = @strSellerNo2 
  END

  .......
```